# My FullCalendar will not parse JS object(array) which is returned from controller when there is dayofWeek

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I want to create a calendar with scheduled event, so I fetched the data from my database into controller, process them into the format as it needed, and return an Json array of event object.However, the calendar do not show the event with daysofWeek.

```
//events is an array of primary key, which will later been used to retrieve data from database in controller
            var a = JSON.stringify(events);
            $(function () {
                $.post('/SchedulingManager/SetVariable',
                    { key: a, value: "Test" }, function (result) {
                        GenerateCalendar(result);
                });
            });
                       }));



        function GenerateCalendar(array) {

            $('#calendar'). fullCalendar({
                //theme: true,
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                },

                buttonText: {
                    today: 'Today',
                    month: 'Month',
                    week: 'Week',
                    day: 'Day',
                },
                timeFormat: 'hh:mm a',
                selectable: true,
                defaultView: 'month',
                editable: true,
                allDaySlot: true,
                selectable: true,

                slotMinutes: 15,
                
                events:array,

            })

        }
    })();
```

[This is the JSON array that is return from the controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZADi1.png)
However, the calendar only shows the event with fix date, but not the events that is with daysofWeek property.( And the time displayed is wrong too for another case).But , when I copy the exactly same code

```
{ dow: '[1,2,3,4,5]', title: 'OFA-0001 : (test event log)', start: ' 10:00:00 ', end: '11:00:00 ' }
```

the event is showned .
[Event is shown if I create the array in view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Idba5.png)

[No weekly event is showed if  the object with daysofWeek is in the array that is retrieved from controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iuvus.png)

Can anynone help me with this I am stuck.Thank you.

Comment: P.S. You tagged the wrong version of fullCalendar, I corrected it for you.

Comment: "But , when I copy the exactly same code the event is shown" ...sorry I can't reproduce that - demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/rNLQPQj?editable=true&editors=001 . Notice that what you've shown here has spaces around the times  - that's the source of your problem, not the days of the week.  Here's a working version (unlike your screenshot, which _should not_ work): https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/YzWRgzR?editable=true&editors=001 . It looks like the feed from your server has the same issue with spaces.